# best practices or solutions to writing resilient programs using unstable slow networks

Tags: networking, network-programming

A program is using a slow unstable network. Frequent timeouts, slow connection etc.

The program uses a few rest APIs and even ssh. The previous developer solved timeout problems by checking for error message and running the same instruction again until it worked. However, sometimes the network connection simply goes dark for a few hours and we have to wait.

We cannot always keep the program alive and waiting (to save power) and end up serializing the state and have another program check for network activity and then wake it up and resume from a serialized state.

The code quality is becoming more and more hackish due to these workarounds.

are there any best practices or solutions when it comes to writing programs for unstable networks? I'm wondering if someone already solved that problem through a library or some book you could recommend?

Thank you

PS: I have no control over the network infrastructure.

Comment: What language is the program written in?  I have the same or a similar question in .NET

Comment: @roryap mix of C and python